# xmessage long text - wrap?

Tags: linux, unix, gnome

I want to use xmessage (it is the only available in the release I am using sorry) to display a message to the user. The message is a bit long and does not fit in one line. xmessage displays the message in one line up the point that is visible.

Is there any way to automatically wrap the text?

I tried the trick to

```
echo -e " message line 1 \n message line 2" | xmessage -file -
```

BUT because my message is coming from a variable and I want to also use it in my logger I do not want to use the "\n" in it. Do I have any chances?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the text through `fmt`.